# Deploy app to iPhone wirelessly?

Tags: iphone, deployment, sdk, wireless

I remember hearing about how Apple was going to include the ability to deploy an app from Xcode to your iPhone wirelessly in the 3.1 SDK.  I believe it was to aid developers that wanted to deploy/test apps that used peripherals that plugged into the iphone's docking port- this way, they could deploy a build of the app with their peripheral device still plugged in.

Has anyone done this, or have a clue as to how to do this?  Is it done via wifi network, via a direct bluetooth connection to the mac...?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can't deploy, but you can use Instruments over Wifi to performance tune your app.

You still need to use USB to allow for Xcode to install and debug your app.

Comment: That's what I heard, as well.